# duplicate data in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i´m trying automate information in my blade. I have a contract, this contract have one or more installable items. i´m doing a `foreach`  and generate `h6` with name and cuantity.

In my db only have one item:

[image]

if i do `dd()` from `$itemsInstallation->item` return this item information:

[image]

but when i do my foreach to create h6 with information, all data it´s duplicated:

[image]

Contract, have relation with itemsContract, and itemsContract have a relation with items. I´m getting ok item information, but i don´t know why my data it´s duplicated. To create foreach, i´m doing:

```
@foreach ($itemsInstallation as $item)
   <h6>{{ $itemsInstallation->item->name }} -- {{ $itemsInstallation->cuantity }} uds</h6>
@endforeach
```

Anybody, can say me that i´m doing bad? thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english.

**I resolve my problem**

reviewing all my logic, i can show that my relationship was wrong, i has a `hasOne` instead of `hasMany`. Now my foreach, it´s a simple for:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($itemsInstallation->item); $i++)
    <h6>{{ $itemsInstallation->item[$i]->name }} -- {{ $itemsInstallation->item[$i]->cuantity }} uds</h6>
@endfor
```

Comment: I've answered but I've noticed that you only got one object, would you please share `dd($itemsInstallation)` or `dd(response()->json($itemsInstallation))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `foreach` loop but instead of calling item you're calling array.

It should be like that:

```
@foreach ($itemsInstallation as $item)
   <h6>{{ $item->name }} -- {{ $item->cuantity }} uds</h6>
@endforeach
```

You can use Forelse which has empty condition, saves you from error when there will be no data.

```
@forelse ($itemsInstallation as $item)
   <h6>{{ $item->name }} -- {{ $item->cuantity }} uds</h6>
@empty
@endforelse
```

For more information visit: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#loops

Comment: thanks for your response, i resolve my problem. in my question i have a solution

Comment: On that you have used `for` loop, you can do this through `@forelse`  which has empty condition and that helps when no data is passed you'll be safe without any error.